Why are backslash and vertical bar characters being not being matched in an if statement?
I have this string:
(335, 'Anschutz 1710/1712', '<p>\r\n   <a href=\"" onclick=\"window.open(this.href, \'\', \'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no\'); return false;\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"\" style=\"width: 780px; height: 659px;\" /></a></p>\r\n', 1, 17, '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 88, '', 0),
And I've been trying to deserialize it, but I need to get rid of the characters with \ in front of them. So I tried doing a simple if(character == '\\') to match it, but that only catches the second \' after this.href, meaning that somehow it skipped 5 backslashes before suddenly stopping on this one.
This is the code I've written to deserialize the string:
        public static string[] RipASQLQuery(string data)
        {
            // Remove the SQL stuff
            var str = data.Replace("(", "");
            str = str.Replace(")", "");
            str = str.Replace(";", "");

            var list = new List<string>();
            int i = 0;
            bool inSubstring = false;
            bool escaped = false;
            foreach (var character in str.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (list.Count < i + 1)
                {
                    list.Add("");
                }

                if (escaped)
                {
                    // Ignore this character
                    Console.WriteLine("Escaped " + character);
                    escaped = false;
                    continue;
                }

                if (inSubstring)
                {
                    if (character == '\'')
                        inSubstring = false;                     
                    list[i] += character;
                    continue;
                }

                if(character == ('\\')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Backslash!!");
                    escaped = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (character == '\'')
                {
                    inSubstring = true;
                    list[i] += character;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(character == ',')
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    list[i] += character;
                }
            }
            return list.ToArray();

I tried to str.Replace("\\", "|"); to try to see if I can match a different character, which successfully changed the string to:
335, 'Anschutz 1710/1712', '<p>|r|n    <a href=|"|" onclick=|"window.open(this.href, |'|', |'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no|' return false|"><img alt=|"|" src=|"|" style=|"width: 780px height: 659px|" /></a></p>|r|n', 1, 17, '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 88, '', 0,
But it still gets caught at the second |' after this.href. I'm very confused.

Where is the string coming from? - because it looks like a source code string literal, where something like (excerpt) "<a href=\"" onclick=\"window.open.." will be seen by the compiler as <a href=" onclick="window.open... - that is, the \" is a source code escape for a literal " within the string.

The easiest way:
str = str.Replace(@"\", "");
Or
str = str.Replace(@"\", String.Empty);
